# Where is ethereum and etc stored on my desktop when using Jaxx wallet?

Tags: windows, backup, jaxx, access

There was an error when opening my jaxx wallet for windows 10 desptop (containing eth and etc), and my computer suggested to reinstall the application. Without thinking, I deleted the jaxx files (but not the app data), and reinstalled Jaxx (this time as an extention on chrome). I had to insert my back up phrase, but I did not save it. 
I moved all Jaxx document from my recycle bin back to my documents. But, when opening the program, it gives two errors stating 'note.dll' and 'ffmpeg.dll' are missing on my pc.

How can I restore my coins? I think it can be done by either fixing the errors stated above, or by doing something (but what?) with the file where my jaxx wallet data is saved: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Jaxx\Local Storage with the file name: file__0.localstorage

Does somebody knows how I can gain acces again to my Jaxx wallet and thus get back my ethereum and ethereum classic?

Comment: Just install the app on your mobile and recover from your phrase.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to restore and recover your wallet by following this Jaxx Knowledge base solution:

https://decentral.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/235539807-Where-are-the-Jaxx-files-stored-on-my-desktop-Can-I-recover-my-wallet-on-my-hard-drive-

Then just rename the "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Jaxx" folder to something else, make a new "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Jaxx\Local Storage" folder, copy and paste file__0.localstorage into "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Jaxx\Local Storage" folder. Next the install the latest version of Jaxx Desktop and run it to let it onboard/initialize the wallet, you will need to initialize each coin wallet using the "<" or ">" and clicking on the coin name. Then Go to options->tools->backup wallet->View Backup Phrase and write down your wallet backup phrase and put it in a safe place, really this time.